# Generate list of tables/ views hit by a list of queries in Snowflake

Tags: query, snowflake

Snowflake provides a list of queries against the databases in account_usage.query_history. I'd like to dive deeper into what tables/ views are being hit most often -- but often there are very complicated views/ queries being fired off.

I'm trying to use the following for now that will parse out the base tables being hit by a particular query - but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

```
DECLARE
  rs RESULTSET;
  query VARCHAR DEFAULT 'EXPLAIN ' || (SELECT query_text from account_usage.query_history where query_id = '01a6b5ca-0614-c192-0000-12d13e8b7abe');

BEGIN
  rs := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
  RETURN TABLE(rs);
END;
select distinct objects from TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()))
```

Comment: Of course ideally I would pass through all query text/ query ids in say a given week or given month to generate the frequency that base views/ tables are queried -- but maybe there's an easier approach?

Comment: Ah it seems this info is generally in Access_history in Snowflake